# column-break-after(before):avoid?

Tags: css

> .newspaper{height:100%;-webkit-columns:100px 5;-webkit-column-rule-width : 1px;-webkit-column-rule-style : solid;-webkit-column-rule-color : red;
>   }
>
> .newspaper h1:nth-of-type(4){-webkit-column-break-after:avoid;border:solid 1px red}

```
<div class="newspaper">
    <h1>The header of the first column</h1>
    <div>Some content within Some content within Some content within Some content within</div>
    <h1>The header of the second column</h1>
    <div>Some content within</div>
    <h1>The header of the third column</h1>
    <div>Some content within Some content within Some content within Some content within Some content within Some content within Some content within Some content within</div>
    <h1>The header of the fourth column</h1>
    <div>Some content within  Some content within Some content within Some content within</div>
</div>
```

From the code, should the fourth H4 element be followed by div elements?
It doesn't seem to work as I expected, is it correct?
Or isn't the option supported by browsers yet?

If I set options as 'left, right, or always', it shows all the same view. 'auto and avoid' also show the same view. Why is that? Is there any condition to use these options?

Do I need to wrap the element with div, or should it be a block level element?